# Springboot app getting stuck at startup in Docker with Java 10

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

**Solution**

Error existed between chair and keyboard

The problem was that the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable was pointing to a profile that didn't exists. Changing it to the correct name fixed the issue. I would have expected Spring to output an error about that, but oh well.

**Original question:**

I have a "hello world" Java App build running with Spring boot in Java10. It runs fine directly on my machine, but when trying to start it up with docker it gets stuck with the following output:

```
(The Srping ascii art)

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/groovy-2.4.15.jar!/) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

The process running:

```
java -Xmx800m -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

It runs fine directly on my laptop (Mac OS), and on my coworker's (Windows 7), but it fails in docker both locally and on Kubernetes (AWS)

I have tried configuring spring log level to DEBUG, but with no effect. 
I also tried to edit `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security/java.security` to change directly the java securerandom.source property, which  didn't work either.

Edit: 
The dockerfile is a FROM using this:

```
FROM openjdk:10-jdk

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssl curl
ADD java.security /docker-java-home/conf/security/java.security

ONBUILD ARG BUILD_VERSION_NO="no-version"

ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
#ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n"

ONBUILD COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ONBUILD RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ONBUILD RUN echo "$BUILD_VERSION_NO" > /version

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar" ]
```

The java version in my laptop is

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Packaging the app with the equivalent openjdk doesn't solve the problem

```
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: May you show us your Dockerfile ? Which version of Java10 do you use on your laptops ?

Comment: @NayoR I edited the question adding the info you asked for

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "it gets stuck" ?
(WARNING is not supposed to block an app)

Comment: I would expect the rest of the spring log, and that  at some point the app would start responding to the healthcheck and other endpoints. It never happens.
(PSA: A coworker is telling me that he has found some issue in one of the libraries that's blocking the threads. I'll update as soon as a I get more info)

Comment: @NayoR I updated the question with the resolution. It was not about either docker or java10. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case someone else bumps into this:

The SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable contained "prod" whereas the spring profile in the application was "pro". Changing the value in the Dockerfile fixed the issue.